# PHPUnit Laravel couldn't update in ut

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, phpunit

I have been meeting an annoying problem when using phpunit. 
I found my database is not updated, after an eloquent method is triggered, 
so the result of the unit test is always wrong.

The code is as below:

```
$testTaskUser = TestTaskUser::find(\SeederConstants::$TEST_TASK_USER_ID);
$testTaskUser->update(array(
            'status' => TestTaskUserStatus::$INITIALIZED
    ));
$this->assertEquals($testTaskUser->status,TestTaskUserStatus::$INITIALIZED);
//This assert fails because the 'status' is not updated in the db, which is 
//Very confusing to me
```

The phpserver and mysql is running in vm in Ubuntu, on my Macbook air.
Anybody can help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Not nearly enough info to work with. Can you `var_dump($testTaskUser);` just before the assert? Have you confirmed that the update works normally? Is the model set to be "fillable" for the status attribute?

Comment: Hi Chris, I found it is because model->update() simply does not work for me.  If I change to this  $testTaskUser->status = TestTaskUserStatus::$INITIALIZED;  $testTaskUser->save();    And this is the right way for me to update.  Very wired

Comment: As mentioned, you can use update, but you need to set the fillable attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure that for `TestTaskUser` user you've added `status` column to `$fillable`.

```
protected $fillable = ['status'];
```

Please look at [mass assignment section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models)

Alternatively you can change your code from:

```
$testTaskUser->update(array(
            'status' => TestTaskUserStatus::$INITIALIZED
    ));
```

to:

```
$testTaskUser->status = TestTaskUserStatus::$INITIALIZED;
$testTaskUser->save();
```

and in this case you don't need to fill in `fillable` property

Comment: Hi Marcin! Thank you so much, I do can use ->save() to update. But strange thing is, my teammates they can use update() for the same unittest. And our model did not set 'status' as fillable....that's very strange again why they can, i can't . PS: they vm are running in Windows 8

Comment: @user3578004 In my opinion it's not possible or you have some very custom setting and setting some properties from configuration files

Comment: Hi Marcin, we do run the same code, but get different results.  The suspicious point here is, our Seed for UT will perform Eloquent::unguard();   and this line seems work for them, but not work for me.  I tried my self here $testTaskUser::unguard(); and $testTaskUser->update, it works then. So I really dont know why Eloquent::unguard() does not work in my root Seeder.  Can you give me a hint about this ?